# PHP Script on back-end when click on button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla2.5

I'm working on joomla environment. I would like to run small php script by click on button event from JQuery reason I would like to use JQuery is I cannot modified existing component. Current component adding some values on Database from webpage. I would like to do same thing but from back-end with out notify any thing from another PHP file. I was trying something as code but it's not working.

Is there any other way.?
What is wrong in code.?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#submitButton').click(function(){
    $.post("/automate/UpdateMySql.php");
   });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing a dot. It should be `jQuery('#submitButton').click`.

Comment: and a square bracket at the end! Do you have the habbit at all to check the console for errors?

Comment: dot . is missing here by mistake I have it in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a dot and bracket(with semi-colon) at the end. As per the comments if you want to just Update Date And Time. You can post any random variable to `UpdateMySql.php` and then Create Date And Time there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicked = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#submitButton').click(function(){
  clicked = 1;
  jQuery.post("/automate/UpdateMySql.php" , { click : clicked });
 });
});
</script>
```

In UpdateMySql.php write.

```
$clicked = $_POST['click'];
if(isset($clicked) && !empty($clicked)) {
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = "UPDATE table_name date_time=".$today." WHERE anything = 'anything'";
 if($query) {
   return 'Updated';
 } else {
   return 'Something Went Wrong';
 }
}
```

Comment: it's not doing any thing. Should it work as my description above.?

Comment: Please provide me with your HTML elements that you want to post to UpdateMySql.php

Comment: I would like to update flag file If click on button with current date and time.

Comment: if i run PHP file manually it's works fine but if i run with  $clicked = $_POST['click']; it's not doing any thing. After Clicked on button

Comment: I think there is problem with Jquery it's not going to that PHP page.

Comment: You are sure you are using the main jQuery.js file right??

Comment: yes, I have other functionality in that file and it's working fine.

Comment: Is it possible because that button has already another functionality with onClick event from component.

Comment: Please edit your question and copy the whole code there. Only then I'll be able to solve ur problem.

Comment: it's working after removing    $ from post and use jQuery.post

Comment: I see, yes that's it. My bad, I forgot to change it for you... Sad... :P Glad to help though :)

Answer (score 0):

**Please use:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({ type:'POST',
             url:'/automate/UpdateMySql.php'
             data:{name:'demo',id:"1"},
             sucess:function(xhr) {
                alert('table updated');
            }
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if some one need complete answer in future.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicked = 0;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#submitButton').click(function(){
    clicked = 1;
    jQuery.post("/automate/UpdateMySql.php" , { click : clicked });
     });
   });
</script>
```